# Django, with or without slash, image doesn't show

Tags: python, django

Really stupid thing, however I don't know how to fix it.

In my url.py I have

```
url(r'^triplists', TripList.as_view()),
```

However when I'm trying to get to this page(http://127.0.0.1:8000/triplists) I get this nasty slash at the end of the link.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/triplists/
```

And that's breaking my images.

When I have slash on the end of url  my link to image in my template looks like
http://127.0.0.1:8000/triplists/static/users/Monk/ncBBqkj4i.jpeg

and when I doesn't
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/users/Monk/ncBBqkj4i.jpeg

First doesn't work, second works.

Why this is happening? Why django adds slash? And why it's changing my image link?

Comment: Check here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#append-slash  I think you should update your url pattern to `url(r'^triplists/$', TripList.as_view()),`

Answer (score 0):

You can fix image link issue by adding `/` to you image `src` attribute

```
<img src="/static/users/Monk/ncBBqkj4i.jpeg">
```

If you are using the `staticfiles` app, the `static` tag will take care of that:

```
<img src="{% static 'users/Monk/ncBBqkj4i.jpeg' %}">
```

the result will be the same as above if your `STATIC_URL` is set like mine in settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Does Django really not have a better way to get static URLs in a way that wouldn't break if the application was available e.g. on `/foo` instead of `/`?

Comment: Yes, it have better way than hard coding links, I've updated my answer